# Is it possible to create a new CoreWindow from a XAML application to use as a DirectX swap chain?

Tags: xaml, directx, winrt-xaml, c++-winrt

I need to create a new `CoreWindow` from inside my XAML application because I would like to assign a swap chain to it using `IDXGIFactory2::CreateSwapChainForCoreWindow`.

The reason why I am not using a `SwapchainPanel` in conjunction with `IDXGIFactory2::CreateSwapChainForComposition` is because tools like Nvidia Nsight do not recognize my window. PIX is the only graphics debugger that works with a `SwapchainPanel`.

Comment: Perhaps you should rewrite question to ask how to make Nvidia Nsight recognize your SwapchainPanel. Because that seems to be the X problem here.